# Adding keys and values to the nested dictionary through EntryBoxes and accessing it through Combobox

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, combobox, tkinter-entry

Is it possible to add new keys and values through `Entrybox` and then imediately after that access it through `Combobox` also making sure that the new `key` and `values` of `sub-keys` are physically saved and appended to the `dictionary` right after they were added. When I `print` the newly added `key` and `values` of `sub-keys` everything seems fine, but there are no changes in the `dict1` itslef and the `Combobox`values.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

def add():

    dict1[entrybox.get()] = {'name_company': entrybox1.get(), 'country_company': entrybox2.get()}
    print(dict1)

dict1 = {"": {"name_company": 0,
    "country_company" : 0,},

    "Company1": {"name_company": "Company1 LTD",
    "country_company": "Germany"}}

window =Tk()

var1=StringVar()

entrybox = Entry(window) #adding main key ("Company1") as an example
entrybox.pack()

entrybox1 = Entry(window) #adding value of sub-key ("name_company")
entrybox1.pack()

entrybox2 = Entry(window) #adding value of sub-key ("country_company")
entrybox2.pack()

combo = Combobox(window, value=list(dict1.keys()), textvariable=dict1[var1.get()])
combo.pack()

button = Button(window, text="Add", command=add)
button.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, I think the following code will provide you with what you want, or get you close to your end goal.

The issue with the original stems with storing the entry values somewhere so that they can be retrieved and used as values in the Combobox, as well as being appended to the dictionary.

As a workaround for this, I used two .txt files, one to store values for the Combobox, the other to store the dictionary, both get updated each time the add button is pressed.

The Add function then retrieves the data from the ComboValues.txt file, sorts them into alphabetical order and assigns them to the Combobox. I'm not stating that this is best practice, but it should serve your requirements.

on a sidenote, a tip I would offer would be to avoid using * when import modules. it can end up getting messy, try and just import what you need, eg. Combobox, Stringvar, Entry ......etc.

Hope this helps, any question or clarification hit me up.

```
import os
from tkinter import Entry, StringVar, Tk, Button
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

Root = Tk()
#set combobox values to empty list
ComboboxValue = []

#String variables for dictionary values
MainKey = StringVar()
SubKey1 = StringVar()
Subkey2 = StringVar()

#Set dictionary values to open list
Dict = {}

#A place to save dictionary key values to read from later
file = open('Combovalues.txt', 'a')

#defining the function for adding entry values to dictionary
def Add():

#Second dictionary used to update original
    DictUpdated = {MainKey.get():{'name_company':SubKey1.get(), 'country_company':Subkey2.get()}}

#Method to update original dictionary
    Dict.update(DictUpdated)

    print(Dict)

#function to update combobox txt file with entry values
    with open('ComboValues.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write('\n'+(str(SubKey1.get())+'\n'+(str(Subkey2.get()))))
        file.close

#function to update Dictionary txt file with entry values        
    with open('Dictionary.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write('\n'+str((Dict)))
        file.close

#function to sort through entry values saved to combobox txt file, ready for assigning to combobox
def ValueSource():
    with open('ComboValues.txt') as inFile:
        ComboboxValue = [line for line in inFile]
        ComboboxValue = sorted(ComboboxValue)
        return ComboboxValue

#Function to retrieve values from combo txt file and assigned to combobox
def GetUpdatedValues():
    Values = ValueSource()
    Root.Combobox['values'] = Values

#Class to build GUI   
class GUI ():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.EntryMainKey = Entry(Root, textvariable= MainKey).grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        master.EntrySubKey1 = Entry(Root, textvariable= SubKey1).grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
        master.EntrySubKey2 = Entry(Root, textvariable= Subkey2).grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
        master.AddButton = Button(Root, text='Add', command=Add).grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
        master.Combobox = Combobox(Root, state='normal', postcommand=GetUpdatedValues)
        master.Combobox['values'] = ComboboxValue
        master.Combobox.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)

#Mainloop function    
def main():
    GUI(Root)
    Root.mainloop()

main()
```